# How do you install Firebase Crashlytics

Tags: android, ios, firebase, react-native, crashlytics

I've been following the docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started) and have made it all the way to the point where I've installed it and am trying to send an error. I added a button to my page that when pressed just does:
`throw new Error('Test Error for Crashlytics')`. I've got it running in my simulator as well as an ad-hoc install of the app onto my phone, but no matter how many times I make my app error, the Crashlytics page in Firebase just shows [image]

I've seen that this can take some time, but I've been waiting about 2 hours now since the first error and about 30 min since I last tried and still nothing. Not really to sure what to try next, I can't seem to find any documentation on how to possibly debug what is going on as well.

Comment: Is your `Error` exception caught by custom code ? If it's the case, crashlytics will not show anything, since the exception is handled (or it must be configured in a way I don't know about). Try something like a division by zero, with no catch clause, and check if something shows up. By default, Crashlytics only handles unhandled exceptions

Comment: As far as I can see there is nothing catching my exceptions. I tried a couple different ways of throwing and error, such as accessing an object that doesn't exist, using a function that doesn't exist as well as just throwing an error. Nothing seems to make it to crashlytics.

Comment: Just when you reached to step 3. clean your project and run again (not reload). Then firebase console detect your app automatically without refresh the page.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase crashlytics will automatically record crashes so you won't need to add anything, unless you have custom requirement. For that you need to follow the [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports).

And for forcing your app to crash, actually you can use

```
Crashlytics.getInstance().crash();
```

[here is the tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/force-a-crash) from firebase documentation.

Comment: Crashlytics is pretty awsome, this should be a standard part of firebase....